# How to find articles which belongs to category in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to display only a  articles which belongs to the category. 
For example: user click on the category and he is getting a list of all articles in this category.

**Article model**

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  belongs_to :user
  #kategorie
  belongs_to :article_category
```

**Article controler**

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def article
    @article = Article.order_by(created_at: 'desc').page params[:page]
  end

  def view_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**ArticleCategory model**

```
class ArticleCategory
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  field :name, type: String

  has_many :articles


end
```

Routes

```
  resources :article_categories do
  resources :articles, shallow: true
  end
```

ArticleCategories Controller

```
class ArticleCategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @article = Article.find
  end

    end
```

In the article view i'm displaying all articles and in articles_categories view i want to show the specific posts. So how should the controler look like( i'm now talking about ArticleCategoriesController .)
I tried using a Article.find_by(name: 'JS') but it is not working. I'm looking for some help :)

Comment: What are you wanting to display on the `index` and `show` views?  All the `ArticleCategory`'s on index? and the `ArticleCategory` with it's `Articles` on the show?

Comment: On the index i want to display all posts in specific category.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class ArticleCategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @category = ArticleCategory.find(params[:id])
        @articles = @category.articles
    end
end
```

Because you `ArticleCategory` model has_many `Articles`, you can do `@categoy.articles`

### UPDATE

Now, to show the articles on the view, you must interact te `@articles` collection (array) like this:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= article.title %><br>
    <%= article.body %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

### UPDATE 2

You can do this to create a link for a category:

```
<%= link_to category.name, category %>
```

### Advise:

I think that you have a basic issues. I recommend you to read something like this:

- https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Will give you a good foundation

Comment: I get ` Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind at /article_categories

Problem:
  Calling Document.find with nil is invalid.  `

Comment: Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided.

Comment: I have the other question for you, how should i display it(i mean the view)? with `@articles` ?

Comment: @KamilMrozek see my Update

Comment: I see the problem, i'm not passing the :id,` <%= link_to "Category", article_categories_path%> ` I was trying to use (:id => article_category.id) but this is not working... How should i pass this id.

Comment: ID comes from params ... URL params like: `http;//localhost:3000/category/1`

Comment: No, when i click on the category, i get `http://localhost:3000/article_categories`

Comment: `<%= link_to "Category", article_categories_path%>`

Comment: Sure, i know but i'm displaying it in the article.html.erb(article view) and your update 2 is not going to work.

Comment: if the article belongs to category, you can do: `<%= link_to article.category.name, article.category %>`